# How to repeat a code segment without the use of function or class for high performance loop in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, inline, compiler-optimization

My program in C++11 is performing an online processing of serialized data and the loop need to run over millions of memory positions. Efficiency on the computation is a must and my concern is that by calling a function or a class within such a loop will create unnecessary operations that will affect efficiency, e.g. transfer of several pointer values needed for the operation between different variable scopes.

To exemplify, let's consider the following dummy example where "something" is the operation that is repeated. Please note that the code within "something" uses the variables within the loop scope.

```
do {
    something(&span,&foo);
    spam++
    foo++
    if ( spam == spam_spam ) {
      something(&span,&foo);
      other_things(&span,&foo);
      something(&span,&foo);
    }
    else {
      something(&span,&foo);
      still_other_things(&span,&foo);
      something(&span,&foo);
    }
}
while (foo<bar);
```

Is there a way to repeat a code block and avoid variables being moved and copied around using unnecessary operations? Does the use of functions and classes on such loops actually implies on additional operations and how one could avoid it?

---

**Update**

As suggested, I ran some tests with the code presented below. I tested several options on how to call a simple increment 100 million times. I'm using GCC over RHEL 7 Server 7.6 on a x86_64 virtual machine under Hyper-V.

Initially, compiling with "g++ -std=c++17 -o test.o test.cpp"

- Simple loop computation (baseline): 211.046ms
- Inline Function: 468.768ms
- Lambda Function: 253.466ms
- Define Macro: 211.995ms
- Function passing values: 466.986ms
- Function passing pointers: 344.646ms
- Function with void: 190.557ms
- Object method operating with members: 231.458ms
- Object method passing values: 227.615ms

From these results I realized that the compiler was not taking the inline suggestion, even after trying to bulge it to do it as suggested at [g++ doesn't inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866861/g-doesnt-inline-functions)

Later, as suggested on the answer from Mat on the same post I turned on the compiler optimizations using "g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -o test.o test.cpp" and got the following result for the same the number of iterations compared with the test without optimization.

- Simple loop computation (baseline): 62.9254ms
- Inline Function: 65.0564ms
- Lambda Function: 32.8637ms
- Define Macro: 63.0299ms
- Function passing values: 64.2876ms
- Function passing pointers: 63.3416ms
- Function with void: 32.1073ms
- Object method operating with members: 63.3847ms
- Object method passing values: 62.5151ms

**Conclusion to this point:**

- inline function is not good alternative because one can not be sure on how the compiler will really take it and the result might be as bad as using a standard function.
- "define macros" and "lambda functions" are better alternatives to inline. Each has its benefits and features, #define being more flexible.
- using object members and methods seams a good balance to solve the problem on any situation while maintaining the code in a form that is easier to maintain and optimize.
- tweaking the compiler is worth it;

Follows the code used for testing:

```
// Libraries
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <chrono>

// Namespaces
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

// constants that control program behaviour
    const long END_RESULT = 100000000;
    const double AVERAGING_LENGTH = 40.0;
    const int NUMBER_OF_ALGORITHM = 9;
    const long INITIAL_VALUE = 0;
    const long INCREMENT = 1;

// Global variables used for test with void function and to general control of the program;
    long global_variable;
    long global_increment;

// Function that returns the execution time for a simple loop
int64_t simple_loop_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            local_variable += local_increment;
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return(duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count());
}

// Functions that computes the execution time when using inline code within the loop
inline long increment_variable() __attribute__((always_inline));
inline long increment_variable(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    return local_variable += local_increment;
}

int64_t inline_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            local_variable = increment_variable(local_variable,local_increment);
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}

// Functions that computes the execution time when using lambda code within the loop
int64_t labda_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // define lambda function
        auto lambda_increment = [&] {
            local_variable += local_increment;
        };

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            lambda_increment();
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}

// define lambda function
    #define define_increment() local_variable += local_increment;

// Functions that computes the execution time when using lambda code within the loop
int64_t define_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            define_increment();
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}
// Functions that compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop passing variable values
long increment_with_values_function(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    return local_variable += local_increment;
}

int64_t function_values_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            local_variable = increment_with_values_function(local_variable,local_increment);
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}
// Functions that compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop passing variable pointers
long increment_with_pointers_function(long *local_variable, long *local_increment) {
    return *local_variable += *local_increment;
}

int64_t function_pointers_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            local_variable = increment_with_pointers_function(&local_variable,&local_increment);
        } while ( local_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}
// Functions that compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop without passing variables 
void increment_with_void_function(void) {
    global_variable += global_increment;
}

int64_t function_void_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // set global variables
        global_variable = local_variable;
        global_increment = local_increment;

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            increment_with_void_function();
        } while ( global_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}
// Object and Function that compute the duration when using a method of the object where data is stored without passing variables
struct object {
    long object_variable = 0;
    long object_increment = 1;

    object(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
        object_variable = local_variable;
        object_increment = local_increment;
    }

    void increment_object(void){
        object_variable+=object_increment;
    }

    void increment_object_with_value(long local_increment){
        object_variable+=local_increment;
    }
};

int64_t object_members_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Create object
        object object_instance = {local_variable,local_increment};

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            object_instance.increment_object();
        } while ( object_instance.object_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Get the results out of the object
        local_variable = object_instance.object_variable;

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}

// Function that compute the duration when using a method of the object where data is stored passing variables
int64_t object_values_computation(long local_variable, long local_increment) {
    // Starts the clock to measure the execution time for the baseline
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    // Create object
        object object_instance = {local_variable,local_increment};

    // Perform the computation for baseline
        do {
            object_instance.increment_object_with_value(local_increment);
        } while ( object_instance.object_variable != END_RESULT);

    // Get the results out of the object
        local_variable = object_instance.object_variable;

    // Stop the clock to measure performance of the silly version
        high_resolution_clock::time_point timer_stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        return duration_cast<microseconds>( timer_stop - timer_start ).count();
}

int main() {

    // Create array to store execution time results for all tests
        pair<string,int64_t> duration_sum[NUMBER_OF_ALGORITHM]={
            make_pair("Simple loop computation (baseline): ",0.0),
            make_pair("Inline Function: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Lambda Function: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Define Macro: ",0.0)
            make_pair("Function passing values: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Function passing pointers: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Function with void: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Object method operating with members: ",0.0),
            make_pair("Object method passing values: ",0.0),
        };

    // loop to compute average of several execution times
        for ( int i = 0; i < AVERAGING_LENGTH; i++) {
            // Compute the execution time for a simple loop as the baseline
                duration_sum[0].second = duration_sum[0].second + simple_loop_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the execution time when using inline code within the loop (expected same as baseline)
                duration_sum[1].second = duration_sum[1].second + inline_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the execution time when using lambda code within the loop (expected same as baseline)
                duration_sum[2].second = duration_sum[2].second + labda_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the duration when using a define macro
                duration_sum[3].second = duration_sum[3].second + define_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop passing variables values
                duration_sum[4].second = duration_sum[4].second + function_values_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop passing variables pointers
                duration_sum[5].second = duration_sum[5].second + function_pointers_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the execution time when calling a function within the loop without passing variables
                duration_sum[6].second = duration_sum[6].second + function_void_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the duration when using a method of the object where data is stored without passing variables
                duration_sum[7].second = duration_sum[7].second + object_members_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);

            // Compute the duration when using a method of the object where data is stored passing variables
                duration_sum[8].second = duration_sum[8].second + object_values_computation(INITIAL_VALUE, INCREMENT);
        }


        double average_baseline_duration = 0.0;

    // Print out results
        for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ALGORITHM; i++) {
        // compute averave from sum
            average_baseline_duration = ((double)duration_sum[i].second/AVERAGING_LENGTH)/1000.0;

        // Print the result
            cout << duration_sum[i].first << average_baseline_duration << "ms \n";
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to measure time and inspect resulting assembly, rather than assume. Many abstractions in C++ can have zero overhead (functions can be inlined, and so on).

Comment: How about inline functions?

Comment: `inline` keyword?

Comment: Are you wanting to use a lambda?

Comment: Did an update with test results using lambda and inline functions. Results are intriguing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is short enough, it can be declared inline and the compiler will put it inline. If it's not, well, then it probably won't help to repeat it.

But, honestly, this is the least effective form of optimisation anyway. Concern yourself with efficient algorithms and cache efficient data structures.

Comment: True about the main concern being the algorithm.

Inline function doesn't seem to be a good idea though. From the update best alternative would be combining the use of object methods and lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested `inline` keyword would do it but there are restrictions (different for each compiler) some do not like loops inside etc ... So if you got something inside that your compiler do not like than the function will not be inline at all...

So if you want better solution without restrictions (for more complicated code) that works always I usually use `#define` for this:

```cpp
// definition
#define code_block1(operands) { code ... }
#define code_block2(operands) { code ... \
 code ... \
 code ... \
 code ... \
 code ... }

// usage:

code ...
code_block1(); // this is macro so the last ; is not needed but I like it there ...
code_block2();

code ...
code_block2();

code ...
code_block1();

code ...
code_block2();
code_block1();
...

// undefinition so tokens do not fight with latter on code
#undef code_block1
#undef code_block2
```

so you simply define your code in form of macro (`#define`) instead of function ... it can use global and local variables ... The `{ }` are not needed but its a good idea so the macro is behaving the same way as a singular expression. That will prevent latter on headaches once you start using stuff like:

```cpp
for (i=0;i<100;i++) code_block1();
```

without the `{ }` inside macro the code would break as only the first expression inside macro would be inside the loop ... which is not obvious from a quick look at the code.

For short code you can write the stuff into single line but if the code is long you can divide the define into multi line by using `\`. Beware do not use comments `//` inside define lines as that would comment out everything even code after used macro in your code... so If yo must have comments use `/* ... */` instead.

The `(operands)` part is optional for no operands it would be just

```cpp
#define code_block1 { code ... }
```

The `#undef` part is optional depends on that if you want to have such macros across your whole code or just locally in some function, class, file ... Also as you can see only the token name is used in macro no operands at all.

I am using this a lot for example see:

- [How to detect robot direction from Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178781/2521214)

and look for `loop_beg` and `loop_end` ... Its a loop macro with usage:

```
loop_beg custom_code; loop_end
```

that is why it does not have the `{}` as the `{` is in `loop_beg` and the `}` is in `loop_end`.

Comment: It's true that the compiler won't always inline, however if you're using a decent compiler, in most cases where it won't inlining your code won't make things faster.

Comment: @JackAidley agree but this has other advantages ... like its passing no operands at all so it does not have call overhead unlike (non)inline which is the major performance difference especially for stuff inside iteration loops ... stack/heap trashing can slows things down a lot in such cases (even passing just pointer is sometimes a problem)...